# Excel Formula / Techniques

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have this question but im pondering how to do.

Scientists at the Research Institute for Robotics have created a new type of robot that reproduces itself. The new robot takes two weeks to gather materials and then builds one new robot (exactly like itself) each week for three weeks. The first new robot is activated at the end of week 3, the second new robot is activated at the end of week 4, and the third new robot at the end of week 5. As soon as it is created, each new robot goes thought the same cycle of gathering materials for two weeks and then creating three new robots, one per week. As so on for each of the new robots. At the end of the first five weeks of its existence each new robot ceases building new robots but retires and “lives” forever. The scientists plan to build only one robot with their own hands and then set it in motion. Create a worksheet that will tell you how many robots there will be in two years.

What formulas or functions should i use?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah i read the homework tag and apologize for my mistake. Im not seeking full solution as i want to do it on my own. But im stuck as i tried to figure out the logic behind it. Really appreciate if anyone could explain but not show. Once done, i will share the solution myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Isolate what information the user is
   giving you.
2. Create an algorithm for finding out
       your answer given the input.
3. Convert the algorithm into a
       function.
4. Create a user interface to let the
       user input values and display the
       answers.